# If A is a set and A ⊂ A×A, then prove that A = Empty Set

Tags: set-theory, axioms

> If $A$ is a set and $A\subset A\times A$, then prove that $A=\varnothing$.

In the exercise, it says that I am supposed to use Zermelo-Fraenkel axioms to prove this statement.

I have tried to use Axiom of Regularity to an extent, but couldn't figure out anything from there to precede.

---

> (Axiom  of Regularity):  $\forall x\,(x\neq \varnothing \rightarrow \exists y\in x\,(y\cap x=\varnothing ))$.

EDIT: I realize that a similar question has been asked but the answer I am looking for specifically involves only the Zermelo-Fraenkel axioms. So the other answer is not sufficient for me. Any contribution will be appreciated.

Comment: What about that answer is insufficient? It only uses ZF ... (*Disclaimer: that answer is mine.*) In case the issue is the use of the term "rank," this is indeed a concept of ZF alone: see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_universe).

Comment: Now when looking with a better understanding I am able to understand the answer which you have written. Thank you for your contribution and for sparing the time of yours for me. Much appreciated.